# Can I use hotwired turbo.js offline?

Tags: flask, turbo

I'm trying to use turbo-flask in my python flask application. It tries to download turbo.js but failes because I'm not working with an internet connection.
I thought about inserting the js file directly into my project but couldnt find it anywhere.
Is it possible to use it offline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: YES.

You can install Turbo as instructed in [Turbo Handbook](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/installing)
But that's without [turbo-flask](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/turbo-flask) package, which uses CDN version as default.
But it seems like you can do (for example) this:

```
{{ turbo(url=url_for('static', filename="node_modules/@hotwired/turbo/dist/turbo.es2017-umd.js")) }}
```

and then your app uses this downloaded js.
This code is from my project, using `npm`. If you don't you need to change the path accordingly.

Comment: turbo refer to cdn and this use in <script> tag will cause issue with turbo navigation as this will be dynamic, and turbo navigation does not like dynamic in script tag.

Comment: I don't completely understand what you mean, @DimitriKopriwa. Can you explain in more detail please?

Comment: By that I mean do not take the module version using this method, use the umd version which doesn't require content within script tag elsewhere turbo navigation cannot be activated due to js content being dynamique with jinja

Comment: Ah, thanks! Yes, I posted original answer as general answer as it's described in turbo-flask docs. I updated it to use `umd`, pasted actual code I'm using in my project.